# Как сделать так, чтобы, когда пользователь нажимал на кнопку, бот отправил фото?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Здавствуйте, возможно вопрос довольно глупый, но я пытаюсь разобраться в ботах всего пару дней. Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы, отправляя слово, бот в ответ отправлял фото. Памагити

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from requests import get


token = 'тут токен'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    buttonA = types.KeyboardButton('Питер')
    buttonB = types.KeyboardButton('/start')
    buttonC = types.KeyboardButton('Как дела?')

    markup.row(buttonA, buttonB)
    markup.row(buttonC)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Я нихрена не умею!', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def ra(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Питер':
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('ссылка', 'rb'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

`bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('ссылка', 'rb'))`

заменить на

`bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'ссылка')`

Comment: Спасибо огромное